# Flask login results in error on correct password (using peewee)

Tags: python, sqlite, authentication, flask, flask-peewee

I'm currently trying to build an app by taking and adjusting parts of the example app included with the `flask-peewee` extension ([code here](https://github.com/coleifer/flask-peewee/tree/master/example)). I can now register and show the login screen. When I enter incorrect login credentials, I get a message that login credentials are incorrect (as expected). But when I enter the correct login credentials, I get a huge traceback from which I cannot find the answer.

Normally I then look into the method or the template to see what's wrong. In this case however, pretty much everything (the method and the template) is handled by peewee.

Below I will first paste the Traceback, followed (as requested in the comments) by the couple files that I currently have. Any information on what could be wrong is very welcome!

Traceback:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_peewee/auth.py", line 170, in login
form.password.data,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_peewee/auth.py", line 128, in authenticate
if not user.check_password(password):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_peewee/auth.py", line 25, in check_password
return check_password(password, self.password)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_peewee/utils.py", line 138, in check_password
salt, hsh = enc_password.split('$', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

The files that I have right now are:

- main.py
- app.py
- auth.py
- config.py
- models.py

Below I will paste the contents of all, in which some things may be omited for clarity:

main.py

```
from app import app
from models import *
from views import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_peewee.db import Database

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.Configuration')

db = Database(app)
```

auth.py

```
from flask_peewee.auth import Auth
from app import app, db
from models import User
auth = Auth(app, db, user_model=User)
```

config.py

```
class Configuration(object):
    DATABASE = {
        'name': 'mydatabase.db',
        'engine': 'peewee.SqliteDatabase',
        'check_same_thread': False,
    }
    DEBUG = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'shhhh'
```

models.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask_peewee.auth import BaseUser
from peewee import CharField, BooleanField, ForeignKeyField, TextField, DateTimeField, IntegerField
from app import db

class User(db.Model, BaseUser):
    username = CharField()
    password = CharField()
    name = CharField()
    registered = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    active = BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: It would be easier if we could see some code

Comment: @Paco - Absolutely true, but I'm unsure which code to show. I don't have a method or template for the login since that is taken care of by peewee. I added my model to the question. If you know of any other code that I could show you, let me know. Can you say anything from this code?

Comment: In order to find the bug, try getting rid of all piece of code that is not causing the problem until you have a very small program that will trigger the error, and that is easy to test.

Comment: @Paco - Thanks, the thing is that I already have a pretty minimal setup. I just started copying things from the example code and pasting them in a new folder to test what everything does. I guess I'm actually missing a piece of code, but I wouldn't know which part, and the traceback doesn't really give me any clues..

Comment: If you have a small piece of code, then you can edit your post and add it ;)

Comment: @Paco - I added all the code that I have

Comment: Did you set the password using the `set_password()` function (which takes the raw text password as input and stores the hashed password)? `check_password()` will only work if you did this. Can you show the code in views.py that takes care of registration and user login?